# Collapse filters in rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I have installed Magento 1.9.0.0 and have started tweaking the rwd theme. I want to collapse the filters list on product listings so that only the headers show and you can click on the header to see your options for that filter. I am far from being an expert in Magento and despite digging around in the files and googling for answers for some time I am none the wiser. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dt = jQuery('#narrow-by-list dt'),
        dd = jQuery('#narrow-by-list dd');
        dt.next().hide();
        dd.first().show();
        dt.first().addClass('active');
        dt.click(function(){
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
    })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, where will I put that?

Comment: Anywhere is your site, footer.phtml will work

Comment: Once I'd remembered to put this between `<script></script>` tags, this worked beautifully. The Price filter remains open but can be shut and all the others are closed and can be toggled open and shut. Thanks again Ahmed.

Comment: still a perfectly good solution in 2017 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to collapse the first filter automatically, you can use the following snippet (just two parts out commented):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dt = jQuery('#narrow-by-list dt'),
        dd = jQuery('#narrow-by-list dd');
        dt.next().hide();
//         dd.first().show();
//         dt.first().addClass('active');
        dt.click(function(){
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
    })
    }); 
</script>
```